# No pointer decay during assignment to pointer-to-fixed array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I've recently discovered the syntax for pointers to fixed arrays. While experimenting with it, I was surprised to see that pointer decay didn't seem to work as in the below example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  char pa[3];
  //char (*parr)[3] = &pa; // This works.
  char (*parr)[3] = pa;    // This doesn't work - why?
  std::cout << (void*)pa << std::endl;
  std::cout << (void*)parr << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
prog.cpp:10:21: error: cannot convert 'char*' to 'char (*)[3]' in initialization
char (*parr)[3] = pa;
       ^
```

Compilation performed with gcc-4.9.2 (Code Chef).

Can someone please help identify what is wrong here?

**Update**:

This is an interesting but even more puzzling finding: the pointer decay works as expected if compiling C-style (I selected "C" as the compiler in Code Chef, although it still shows gcc-4.9.2. Perhaps there are different compiler flags being passed to differentiate between C and C++ compilation.)

The C version of the above code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  char pa[3];
  /* char (*parr)[3] = &pa; */
  char (*parr)[3] = pa;
  printf( "0x%x\n", pa);
  printf( "0x%x\n", parr);
  return 0;
}
```

Output from the compiled C code:

```
0xbf92b1fd
0xbf92b1fd
```

Comment: Why bother with old-style C arrays when modern C++ has `std::array` and `std::vector`?

Comment: If you are using c++, consider using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with

```
char (*parr)[3] = pa;
```

Is that `parr` is a pointer to an array, which is not the same as a pointer to the first element of an array(which is what an array name can decay into).  In order to get it to work you need the address of `pa` like

```
char (*parr)[3] = &pa;
```

Comment: Do you know why the nonworking pointer decay syntax in C++ seems to work in the C-style code? I wouldn't have expected this to be a point of difference between C and C++.

Comment: Also, are you saying that `&pa[0]` is different than `&pa`? I'd always treated them interchangeably, but I'd also never before used the "pointer to fixed array" syntax before.

Comment: @StoneThrow I do not know C well enough to hazard a guess.  C does allow a lot of implicit pointer conversions that C++ does not so I would expect it to be related to that.  Like void* automatic cast in C but not C++.

Comment: @StoneThrow `&pa[0]` is a pointer to the first element.  `&pa` is a pointer to what decays to a pointer to the first element.  Basically `T*` vs `T**`.

Comment: I would have expected exactly what you said regarding T* vs. T**, but in the C-style code, if I change `char (*parr)[3] = pa;` to `char (*parr)[3] = &pa;`, the output is the same (and for that matter, I would have expected it to not compile, because a double-pointer doesn't apply here).

Comment: In this case `&pa[0]` is a `char*` pointing to the first element. `&pa` is a `char (*)[3]` pointing to the array. They have the same value but a different type.

Comment: I'm going to change the title of this question to make it about the C vs. C++ difference, because that seems to be the issue that's becoming dominant.

Comment: @StoneThrow Your changing the semantics of the question then which kind of invalidates my answer.  IMHO it should be another question to ask what about C allows it to work when it does not work in C++.

Comment: @NathanOliver - Fair enough. I'll post as a separate question and restore the title.

Comment: @StoneThrow It works in C for you because of a compiler extension. GCC rejects it only if `-pedantic-errors` is present.

Comment: @NathanOliver - going back to the original issue: I kind of get what you're saying. But I'm still a bit unclear: you say "`parr` is a pointer to an array, which is not the same as a pointer to the first element of an array". Does this mean that given `char pa[3]`, then `pa` decays into `&pa[0]` and is different than `&pa`? I always thought that `&pa` was equivalent to `&pa[0]` because I've been able to use them interchangeably except in this specific case of assignment to a pointer to a fixed array.

Comment: @StoneThrow `&pa` and `&pa[0]` are the same address, but the types are different - one points to an array and one points to an element of that array. This is similar to taking the address of a struct/class vs taking the address of the first data member of that struct/class.

Comment: @Kevin - that's a great analogy. I get it. I think that explains why I've been able to get away with using them interchangeably: because for those functions that take a `char*` (or lvalues being assigned), all that matters is the pointer value, which is the same between `&pa` and `&pa[0]`, whereas in the case where the lvalue is a pointer to a fixed array, the type is relevant - is that right?

Comment: Due to the difference in types you should get a compiler warning/error about a type mismatch if you were to use `&pa` in place of `&pa[0]` or `pa` (which is equivalent to `&pa[0]` due to decaying) or vice versa. Decaying often causes some confusion, as helpful as it can be.

Comment: @Kevin - In all my years of coding, I've _never_ seen such a compile warning. And I've seen engineers at all levels of seniority use these syntaxes interchangeably. This was an unexpectedly useful Q&A session. I learned a lot more than I thought was behind the original question.